# Meteor Cron Job Last Time Increment

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am developing a simple oldschool browser game where there are cities and their productions.

Lets say that for level 1 city stone production is 1 per minute.

For level 5 city stone production is 60 per minute.

The problem is currently i have a setInterval function in server  with 0 interval which is looping through db checking cities and their productions and incremeting(?) them.

So how do i increment correctly ? Since all cities has different productions per minute what is the correct aproach ? Do i need to store last increment time of each city in db  then check if enough time is passed and then increment ?

Also since i am real time updating data from db to client,i would like to see incrementing 1 by 1 not +60 after 1 minute pass.

What I tried so far :

```
function resourceUpdater(){ 
    Towns.find({}).forEach( town => { 
        if(town.spot1.buildingName =="factory" && town.spot1.level==1){ 
            Towns.update( {_id:town._id},{$inc:{"resources.stone":1}}) 
        } 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Any code you can share to show us what you did to try and solve your problem ?

Comment: i dont think this code explains my problem  but... : https://pastecode.xyz/view/fcab6837

Comment: What is this function? What does it do? What is it trying to achieve? You spoke of a `setInterval function` you currently have, where is it? Please share everything you can, if you can't ask a proper question while giving all the information you can no one will bother answering.

Comment: Why not just save start and end dates, targeted values and incrementation amount values on the server, let client subscribe and let the clients do the timer and update display based on these values? Saves you a lot of resources on the server and it will scale more linear.